# CSS angular simple form is broken on firefox

Tags: html, angular, css, responsive-design

I am developping an angular 4 application.
I started with a simple html form and customise the css when i run the project all things work good on chrome but on firefox the css is modified and all inputs are not organized.
This my html code:

```css
.RegisterTitle{
    padding-bottom: 5%; 
    display:inline-flex;
    }

    .Retour{
        display: inline-flex; align-items: center;
    }
    
    .centrer {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 50%;
        background-color: white;
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 4%;
        padding-left: 5%;
        padding-right: 5%;
    }
    body{
        background-color: #ddd;
    }
    .page {
        background-color:#ddd;}
    
    
    .al-blue{
    
     color:red;
    }

    .form-control{
        width: 130%;
        
    }
    .btn{
        width: 130%;
    }
    .g1{
        max-width: 80%;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 20%;
    }
    .field-icon {
      float: right;
      margin-left: -25px;
      margin-top: -25px;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    form{
        margin-left: 5%;
        margin-right: 5%;
    }
    .g2{
        max-width: 80%;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 20%;
    }

    .btn-al-blue{
    
       background-color: red;
        color: white;
    }
    
    .lien {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    
    .bottom {
        margin-top: 12%; 
    }
    
    .top {
        margin-top: 10%; 
    }
    
    .errColor {
        color: red;
    }
    .iconColor {
        color: #328DF3;
        margin-right: -2%;
    }
```

```html
     <div class="centrer">
    <div style="padding-bottom: 5%; display:inline-flex">
      <h4 class="al-blue">Add form</h4>
      <a  style="padding-left: 120%;padding-top: 3%" >
       
       <div style="display: inline-flex; align-items: center;"> <i class="fas 
         fa-angle-left"></i> Cancel</div>
  
        </a>
      </div>
  
      <form  #signInForm="ngForm">
        
        <div class="form-group  g1 al-blue">
          <label for="text">Name society </label>
          <input type="text" name="nomcompte" ngModel required  class="form- 
       control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group g1 al-blue">
            <label for="text">Langue</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="langue">
                <option   > fr </option>
                <option  > an </option>
              </select> 
          </div>
          <div style="padding-bottom: 2%;margin-top: 3%; display:inline-flex">
              <h5 class="al-blue">Account</h5>
            </div><br/>
          
        <div class="form-group g2 al-blue">
          <label for="text">first name </label>
          <input type="text" name="nomuser" required  class="form-control" 
          
        >
         
        </div>
        <div class="form-group g2 al-blue">
          <label for="text">Last name</label>
          <input type="text" name="prenomuser" ngModel required  class="form- 
 
         control" 
         
             >
   
        </div>
        <div class="form-group g1 al-blue">
          <label for="text">mail</label>
          <input type="text" name="mail" ngModel required  class="form-control" 
      
                  >
         
        </div>
        <div class="form-group g1 al-blue">
          <label for="text">numphone</label>
          <input type="tel" name="numphone" ngModel   class="form-control">

        </div>
        <div class="form-group  g1 al-blue">
          <label for="password">Mot de passe</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" ngModel 
      required >
        </div>
        <div class="form-row bottom">
        
          <div class="form-group">
            <div style="width:65%;">
                <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-al-blue" 
        [disabled]="!signInForm.form.valid">enregistrer</button>
  
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      
      </form>
  </div>
```

And those are [image]two images about what i see on chrome and firefox:

[image]

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gqnqnw

Comment: That is my code it works on chrome like the second image but not in firefox i want someone can help me!

Answer (score 0):

On firefox check with firebug and compare classes with chrome inspect. Your css is not being loaded or some classes are not loaded.

Comment: As Mooga already mentioned, you need to define each class and format fields. You have problems because you use some of browser built-in css to format your form. You centrare class doesn't have positioning of elements nor proper width furthermore, some classes you use to fix position but not in proper way but just like a short fix and when you change browser or change width, it all goes to hell. I would start from deleating all style marks in app.component.html. Where is html and body tags in style.css?

Comment: I just want a form where evrey 2 inputs are in the same line . with my own css (not bootstrap or other things)

Comment: Like the second picture that i puted

Answer (score 0):

You can simpily use that but anyway don't use that kind of code because you need to have more structured code

```css
.RegisterTitle{
    padding-bottom: 5%; 
    display:inline-flex;
    }

    .Retour{
        display: inline-flex; align-items: center;
    }
    
    .centrer {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 50%;
        background-color: white;
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 4%;
        padding-left: 5%;
        padding-right: 5%;
    }
    body{
        background-color: #ddd;
    }
    .page {
        background-color:#ddd;}
    
    
    .al-blue{
    
     color:red;
    }

    .form-control{
        width: 130%;
        
    }
    .btn{
        width: 130%;
    }
    .g1{
        max-width: 80%;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 20%;
    }
    .field-icon {
      float: right;
      margin-left: -25px;
      margin-top: -25px;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    form{
        margin-left: 5%;
        margin-right: 5%;
    }
    .g2{
        max-width: 80%;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 20%;
    }

    .btn-al-blue{
    
       background-color: red;
        color: white;
    }
    
    .lien {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    
    .bottom {
        margin-top: 12%; 
    }
    
    .top {
        margin-top: 10%; 
    }
    
    .errColor {
        color: red;
    }
    .iconColor {
        color: #328DF3;
        margin-right: -2%;
    }
```

```html
     <div class="centrer">
    <div style="padding-bottom: 5%; display:inline-flex;position:relative;width:100%;">
      <h4 class="al-blue">Add form</h4>
      <a  style="position:absolute;top:17px;right:0" >
       
       <div style="display: inline-flex; align-items: center;"> <i class="fas 
         fa-angle-left"></i> Cancel</div>
  
        </a>
      </div>
  
      <form  #signInForm="ngForm">
        
        <div class="form-group  g1 al-blue">
          <label for="text">Name society </label>
          <input type="text" name="nomcompte" ngModel required  class="form- 
       control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group g1 al-blue">
            <label for="text">Langue</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="langue">
                <option   > fr </option>
                <option  > an </option>
              </select> 
          </div>
          <div style="padding-bottom: 2%;margin-top: 3%; display:inline-flex">
              <h5 class="al-blue">Account</h5>
            </div><br/>
          
        <div class="form-group g2 al-blue">
          <label for="text">first name </label>
          <input type="text" name="nomuser" required  class="form-control" 
          
        >
         
        </div>
        <div class="form-group g2 al-blue">
          <label for="text">Last name</label>
          <input type="text" name="prenomuser" ngModel required  class="form- 
 
         control" 
         
             >
   
        </div>
        <div class="form-group g1 al-blue">
          <label for="text">mail</label>
          <input type="text" name="mail" ngModel required  class="form-control" 
      
                  >
         
        </div>
        <div class="form-group g1 al-blue">
          <label for="text">numphone</label>
          <input type="tel" name="numphone" ngModel   class="form-control">

        </div>
        <div class="form-group  g1 al-blue">
          <label for="password">Mot de passe</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" ngModel 
      required >
        </div>
        <div class="form-row bottom">
        
          <div class="form-group">
            <div style="width:65%;">
                <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-al-blue" 
        [disabled]="!signInForm.form.valid">enregistrer</button>
  
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      
      </form>
  </div>
```

I recommend you to use bootstrap or similar